# Visual Studio Code doesn't show output (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I just downloaded Visual Studio Code and in the same breath the C++ extension (working on a Mac Machine). By just testing a simple "hello world" programm, aka

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}
```

the compiling and running works, but unfortunately, it won't show the output in the Visual Studio 'Output' section.
Help would be appreciated.

PS:
The only output I'm getting is

```
[Running] cd "/Users/XYZ/Desktop/MyProject/" && g++ test.cpp -o test && "/Users/XYZ/Desktop/MyProject/"test

[Done] exited with code=null in 0.005 seconds
```

Comment: I assume the program works if you run it from a terminal window.

Comment: How can I make it work in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: `sleep(900)` is an easy answer.

Comment: If I do sth like "cin >> XYZ", it also won't stop.